# Need help about references for 2D delta "function"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, dirac-delta, laplacian

I am writing a paper about some numerical methods in the field of electrostatics and I remember from somewhere that the following equation is true: 
 $$\left(
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
+
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}
\right)
\log{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
=
2\pi\delta(x)\delta(y).$$ 
 Function $\log$ is natural logarithm, i.e. $\log e=1$, and $\delta(x)$ and $\delta(y)$ are Dirac's delta "functions". Unfortunately, I cant remember where in the literature I have seen this equation since the last time I was using it was in 2005. For that  reason, I kindly ask if someone can point me to the papers or books which I can use for reference.

Comment: Would this be better suited on [math.se] (assuming they don't get too upset about the Dirac Delta Function)? Have you tried actually evaluating that expression? I am not sure it gives DDFs

Comment: Yes probably, I wasn't even aware that group exists since I was so focused on explaining some numerical methods in physics. Will try to ask question there, thanks for advice

Comment: Math mods: Please merge.

Answer (score 0):

The expression mathematically is saying that, the natural log function is the Green's function for free-space Laplace equation in 2D. (in 3D it will be the Coulomb 1/r potential)

This is a pretty standard and well-known thing, and be found in almost every standard books either on linear Partial Differential Equations, or Potential Theory. You can also find it in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function

You may check out a few references there. But to be honest, I do not think it is necessary to cite anything. I am in the math department though.

Comment: Yes I know its standard, however I am having trouble finding citable reference in standard books

Comment: I personally will suggest: Kellogg, Foundations of Potential Theory. This is a pretty good book, and there is a whole section about The Logarithmic Potential.